# xdocument re writing xml document

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to edit my **xml file** which is present in picture folder via my **windows store app** on button click.

*I have used following code.*

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("q.xml");


            using (var fileStream = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {

                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileStream);

                xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("drink",
                 new XElement("drinkImage", "pepsi.png"),
                 new XElement("drinkTitle", "PEPSI"),
                 new XElement("drinkDescription", "HelloWorld")));
                xdoc.Save(fileStream);
            }
```

The code is working for me but it rewriting my xml file.

**Before button click my xml file was:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<drinks>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
</drinks>
```

**After button click my xml file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<drinks>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
  <drink>
    <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
    <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
    <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
  </drink>
</drinks>
```

> **// The above stuff shouldn't be there**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <drinks>
      <drink>
        <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
        <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
        <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
      </drink>
      <drink>
        <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
        <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
        <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
      </drink>
      <drink>
        <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
        <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
        <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
      </drink>
    </drinks>
```

Kindly help me through this repetition.

Expected file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <drinks>
          <drink>
            <drinkImage>ck.png</drinkImage>
            <drinkTitle>COKE</drinkTitle>
            <drinkDescription>(1793-1844)</drinkDescription>
          </drink>
          <drink>
            <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
            <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
            <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
          </drink>
          <drink>
            <drinkImage>pepsi.png</drinkImage>
            <drinkTitle>PEPSI</drinkTitle>
            <drinkDescription>HelloWorld</drinkDescription>
          </drink>
        </drinks>
```

Comment: You are re-using the same stream, it writes wher it stopped reading. Reset the file-position or (better) use 2  separate `using (var fileStream = ...) {}`